# How to merge categories and create total per category in PowerBI?

Tags: azure, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

We are migrating a few dashboards from Tableau to PowerBI.

Some of the Tableau table visualization look like this:

[image]

However, I wasn't able to replicate the same thing in PowerBI. The table visualization in PowerBI only allows me to do this:

[image]

Is there a way in PowerBI to merge cells and create totals per group? Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried using the matrix visual?

Answer (score 2):

Use a Matrix visual. You can also go to the formatting option for the Matrix visual and enable Stepped Layout to have a multi-column layout.